# Send data to another process

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, message-queue

I have to make a C program in unix. I have to simulate the results tables of a car race, I already made a code to create some cars (with a fork) and now I'm trying to send the results to another program. That other program will be able to sort the received datas. I want to use message queue or shared memory (I don't know which method is the best in that case) but I don't have a lot of experience is programming so I really don't know how to do that.

Is there someone here who could help me ?

Thank you in advance !

***EDIT :***

So I tried to implement a message queue but I have a segmentation fault. I don't know where that comes from =/

I have 2 struct in each program :

T_Voiture :

```
typedef struct T_voiture    
    {
        int num;
        int stand; //nombre d'arrêts au stand
        bool out;
        int tours; //nombre de tours
        //temps en millisecondes
        int meilleurTemps;
        //meilleurs temps de chaque secteur
        int s1;
        int s2;
        int s3;
        //temps derniers secteurs
        int secteur1;
        int secteur2;
        int secteur3;
        float vitesse;
        double tempsCourse; //temps passé en course, que l'on incrémente à chaque secteur
    }T_voiture;
```

and my_msgbug :

```
struct my_msgbuf {
    long mtype;
    T_voiture mvoiture;
};
```

In my sender program (Voiture1.c) I do 24 fork and in each fork I do

```
struct my_msgbuf buf;
T_voiture v;
v=initialiserVoiture(v,ii);
lancerQualifs(v, longueur, TEMPS_Q1);
msgsnd(msqid, &buf, sizeof(struct my_msgbuf) - sizeof(long), 0);
```

And in my receiver program (Gestionnaire.c) I do :

```
for(;;) { /* Spock never quits! */
        if (msgrcv(msqid, &buf, sizeof(buf.mvoiture), 0, 0) == -1) {
            perror("msgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Voiture : \"%s\"\n", buf.mvoiture.meilleurTemps);
    }
```

First I start Voiture 1.c then Gestionnaire.c. It's when I'm starting the second program that the "segmentation fault" error appears in my terminal. But the connection to the queue seems to run pretty well

I hope that this question is more specific than the last

(and sorry for my english, it's not my mother tongue)

Comment: This is not a place to ask people to write parts of your program for you. Read documentation on shared memory and/or message queues in POSIX, start implementing the approach you want, and then, if your inter-process communication goes wrong - ask us.

Comment: I'm just asking what's the best method to do my job, i'm not trying to get already made code from you guys ^^

Comment: Sorry, but that's not obvious from your question. I'd say that the best method to do your job is to read about IPC in UNIX (messages, shared memory, pipes, semaphores), and you'll see which of them suits.

Comment: I already read a lot of documentation but, as I said, I'm a beginner programmer and I REALLY don't know what to choose between shared memory and message queue

Comment: It's hard to tell what is better from your question. Message queues are often easier to use, but if you are learning, why not to implement it in both ways?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that message queues are easier, shared memory is ok for moving the data about, but you've still got to provide a method of notifying the other process when data is available.